# Phrases similar to "what would you do?"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I'm looking for common phrases similar to "What would you do?" I'd like any phrase that signifies the call to action to make a difficult hypothetical decision.  For example, "Take your pick" is a possible answer because it is a common phrase, but it doesn't work that well in context of making a *difficult* decision so it wouldn't work.

I know this is a really specific request, but ideally the phrase really captures the essence of difficult hypothetical decision, perhaps an ethical dilemma.
E.g. "Would you prefer a slow and mildly painful death, or a quick and very painful one? WHAT WOULD YOU DO?" (replacing *what would you do* with something else)

Comment: I've always been fond of shouting, "QUICKLY! THERE ARE MILLIONS OF LIVES AT STAKE!" Especially when the hypothetical situation I'm presenting is actually far more trivial than that.

Comment: @SampleJACK I was just wondering which answer you would accept because I wanted to know whether my answer was complete or not, since you have (grudgingly) admitted it was thorough, so I guess I don't need to further edit it. As for the threat; go ahead and report it for all I care...

Answer (score 3):

"The ball is in your court", "It's time to decide/choose.", "It's time to make your decision/choice", "It's up to you.",

In any case, I'd follow with a pregnant pause, heh.

Answer (score 2):

Some come to mind:

> Make your decision.
>   Choose for yourself.

E.g.:

> Would you prefer a slow and mildly painful death, or a quick and very painful one? Choose for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of phrases that can be used although the context may slightly vary.

1- What would *you* prefer?

2- What would your decision be?

3- I ask you the same question

4- What is your advice?

5- What would be *your* choice?

6- What is preferable to *you*?

7- The decision stands with you.

8- The decision is up to you.

9- It depends on *your* choice.

10- It depends on *your* decision

11- What would *you* advise?

12- What if *you* were in my place?

13- What would *your* answer be?

14- Why don't you decide for yourself?

15- Why ask me? Decide yourself.

16- The decision is with you.